# I want to send chekkedbox value=True with question answer to Mysql

Tags: checkbox

Hello i have html form for creating an exam  question and i have 1 question and 4 answers when i creating question i want to check to true answer and send this answer to Mysql with True tag and others false.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtx3.png)

`
Soru ?

```
                    <div class="input-group-prepend" id="ask">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteRow" type="button" style="display:none;">
                            <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                            Sil
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="text" name="Soru[]" class="form-control m-input" style="display:none;">

                </div>

                <label for="" class="mb-3" id="l2" style="display:none;">Cevap</label>

                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-75" id="ask1" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="Answer" style="display:none;">A</span>
                    </div>

                    <input type="text" id="text" name="cevap1[]" class="form-control m-input" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox" value="True" name="chk[]"
                            aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="True" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-75" id="ask1" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="Answer" style="display:none;">B</span>
                    </div>

                    <input type="text" id="text" name="cevap2[]" class="form-control m-input" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox" value="True" name="chk[]"
                            aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="True" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-75" id="ask1" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="Answer" style="display:none;">C</span>
                    </div>

                    <input type="text" id="text" name="cevap3[]" class="form-control m-input" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox" value="True" name="chk[]"
                            aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="True" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3 w-75" id="ask1" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="Answer" style="display:none;">D</span>
                    </div>

                    <input type="text" id="text" name="cevap4[]" class="form-control m-input" style="display:none;">

                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox" value="True" name="chk[]"
                            aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="True" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
```

`

befeore send data to mysql i m using cosole log